# Undefined variable: names

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

### I am facing difficulties pushing data from the `Controller` to the `View`. Below is my code script.

I created my controller `ListController` using `artisan`

```
php artisan make:controller ListController
```

ListController - show method

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ListController extends Controller
{

    public function listNames()
    {
        $names = array(
            'Daenerys Targaryen', 
            'Jon Snow',
            'Arya Stark',
            'Melisandre',
            'Khal Drogo'
        );

        return view('welcome', ['names' => $names]);
    }
}
```

Created a view `welcome.blade.php` (which is default)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">API DOCUMENTATION</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    @foreach ($names as $n)
                    <p>{{$n}}</p>
                    @endforeach

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Then, added the appropriate route for it (routes.php)

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'ListController@listNames');
```

When opening `localhost:8000` after running `php artisan serve`, it throws an Exception

```
ErrorException in 56f6d37e6c39b528e3f5a170141b734befe0f7a2.php line 14:
Undefined variable: names (View: /Applications/MAMP/.../views/welcome.blade.php)
```

So far I have tried the following:
In the Controller:

```
return view('welcome', compact('names'));      --> DOESN'T WORK
return view('welcome', $names);                --> DOESN'T WORK
return view('welcome')->with($names);          --> DOESN'T WORK
return view('welcome')->with('names', $names); --> DOESN'T WORK
```

Hard coding the array in the view and assigning it a variable works

```
<?php $names = array('John Snow', 'Arya Stark');?>
<?php foreach ($names as $n):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $n;?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

I can't seem to detect the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not using blade in your blade views though?

Comment: This is very random but you don't have a duplicate project anywhere do you? It's just your error states your files are in a MAMP directory yet you are still using the php artisan serve command which you don't really need to use if you were running MAMP. Probably a long shot but thought I'd ask

Comment: Yes I don't need to use `php artisan serve` and I do have other projects running on MAMP. But, it just makes my life easier with artisan :)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass variables using an array:

```
return view('welcome', ['names' => $names]);
```

Or just:

```
return view('welcome', compact('names'));
```

To check it do this in the view:

```
{{ dd($names) }}
```

Comment: thanks. I have tried all the above and still it shows same error `Undefined variable`

Comment: Yes I did change to `listNames`. Same thing, Shows same error.

Comment: @h4kl0rd please show all routes, maybe there is some conflict there. And did you show whole `welcome` view or just a part of it?

Comment: I have updated my question with the latest updates. Refer to the question.

Comment: @h4kl0rd your code looks fine. The only think I would try is to clear routes and view cache with `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

First, pass your variables as Alexey said,

`return view('welcome', ['names' => $names]);`

And then, on the view, do

`@foreach ($names as $n)
    <p>This is name {{ $n }}</p>
@endforeach`

Documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Route.php >> `Route::get('/', 'ListController@listNames');` And controller method changed to `listNames()`. I have also removed php scripts and used blade format. I don't think the issue is using blade format cause defining the array variable in the view loads the names. But, when I try to push data from controller it shows the `undefined variable` error.

Comment: Try removing cache... worth the shot...
php artisan view:clear

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue.
After spending so much time looking for the bug, I tried to check if laravel version could have something to do with this. The `routes.php` doesn't work in `Laravel v5.3+` and I was using `Laravel v5.4.x`.

The routes are available in a directory called `routes` and so I pasted the code from `routes.php` to `routes/web.php` and **it worked**.

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'ListController@listNames');
```